# Replace word from an Array, and write results to file

Tags: python

I have this paragraph:

"Hello USERNAME,
This email regarding your phone number PHONE_NUMBER"

Now i have list of 10 users, each one has phone number.

I would like to write Python script to replace USERNAME, PHONE_NUMBER with each one from the list.

How i can do that?

Comment: What have you tried? We aren't going to write the code for you...

Comment: Nothing since i don't know where to start from. I'm not asking to write code for me, basically you can point me to the right direction.

Comment: Look into [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) and dictionaries. You should be able to do this in about two lines :)

Comment: @Ahmad Zoughbi Are you able to modify the paragraph so the `USERNAME` and `PHONE_NUMBER` are [Named placeholders](https://pyformat.info/#named_placeholders)? If so, the paragraph would then resemble `mystr = "Hello {USERNAME}, This email regarding your phone number {PHONE_NUMBER}"`. If you can't modify the paragraph, an option would be to use [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace), so something like `mystr.replace('USERNAME', 'John').replace('PHONE_NUMBER', '234567890')`